# SVG animation using inkscape

Tags: animation, svg, inkscape, svg-animate

Im new to SVG animation i have made a cloud using inkscape and i am trying to animate its color.

This is my code :

```
  <path
     style="fill:#ffffff"
     d="m 134.34587,283.69862 c -7.8945,0 -14.35932,6.03786 -15.0625,13.75 -0.63922,-0.0822 -1.27593,-0.12508 -1.9375,-0.125 -8.365,0 -15.15625,6.76 -15.15625,15.125 0,4.0237 1.59649,7.66271 4.15625,10.375 -0.097,0.69271 -0.1875,1.40555 -0.1875,2.125 0,8.365 6.79125,15.125 15.15625,15.125 1.12553,0 2.22565,-0.14207 3.28125,-0.375 1.33966,6.99425 7.4892,12.28125 14.875,12.28125 8.366,0 15.15625,-6.76 15.15625,-15.125 0,-3.73995 -1.3785,-7.17028 -3.625,-9.8125 7.08612,-1.26528 12.46875,-7.45578 12.46875,-14.90625 0,-7.9992 -6.20608,-14.53612 -14.0625,-15.09375 -0.89029,-7.51611 -7.305,-13.34375 -15.0625,-13.34375 z m -1.9375,30.15625 c 0.29122,0.0376 0.57885,0.0729 0.875,0.0937 0.0969,0.81792 0.24679,1.60238 0.46875,2.375 -0.43597,-0.62744 -0.91401,-1.2278 -1.4375,-1.78125 0.0317,-0.22937 0.0725,-0.45498 0.0937,-0.6875 z m 3.46875,6.90625 c 0.28226,0.40629 0.58657,0.8115 0.90625,1.1875 -0.20082,0.0359 -0.39575,0.0813 -0.59375,0.125 -0.0845,-0.44086 -0.19069,-0.88611 -0.3125,-1.3125 z"
     id="top_cloud"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" 
   <animate xlink:href="#top_cloud"
         dur="12s" begin="1s"
         to="#000000" from="#CC9933"
         repeatCount="indefinite"   
         calcMode="linear" attributeName="fill"/> 
</path>
```

Im getting an error while i preview it... 
Can anyone correct me where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `>` after `inkscape:connector-curvature="0"`.